# Cannot connect to AWS RDS SQL Server Database from Azure WebJob

Tags: azure, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I am trying to connect to an SQL Server 2012 database in AWS RDS. Code works in Debug which tends to prove that the connection string, the AWS configuratio... are all good. I checked the connection string deployed in Azure with FTP, it is all well and good but when I call Connection.Open(), I get the following error (relevant part of the stacktrace) :

```
[01/26/2016 12:45:00 > 8c2620: INFO] System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.) ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
[01/26/2016 12:45:00 > 8c2620: INFO]    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
```

I tried to set up a network security group in Azure (allowing all ports/all IPs/TCP/UDP In/Out). It did not help but I was not completely able to understand if the WebJob is impacted by this security group (I am new to Azure and find the interface a bit confusing). Is there a way to link the policy to the job or is the policy applied server wide ?

I should mention that I am using free accounts for both AWS and Azure (which might limit my options ?)

Did anyone get that problem ? Does anyone have any hint ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you also setup security groups on AWS and open the necessary ports?

Comment: @vmachan I do believe the AWS configuration is OK since the SQL queries work on my laptop. I just checked, and apparently, RDS created a security group itself: rds-launch-wizard Created from the RDS Management Console

Comment: Yes, and as per this [AWS link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Overview.RDSSecurityGroups.html), they request you to actually delete the DB security group..  you may want to check it..

Comment: @vmachan OK, hats off to you sir. I was so convinced the problem lied in the Azure configuration, when it was indeed the AWS policy that blocked me. The default security group in AWS only allows the IP of the creator. By adding the IPs of the Azure server, everything works. Thanks again, and if you care to post as an answer, i'll gladly approve it and upvote it.

Comment: Thanks. posted as answer as well, might benefit others too..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Adding this as an answer so that other folks might also benefit*

First check to see if you have the default DB security groups that are created when you host an RDS instance.

If so, As per this [AWS link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Overview.RDSSecurityGroups.html), they request you to actually delete the DB security group.

You should try and remove these and then check connectivity again.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Ok Folks, Try this I am pretty sure it will work
it worked for me
1. Go to security group.
2. Choose the default group.
3. Go to the Inbound group.
4. Click Edit then change the source option from Custom to Anywhere.
5. Save.
That's it
Please reply if it worked.

MohaBassam